# Displaying aggregate in blade Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have following table in database 
[image]

and i have following query

```
      $users = DB::table('results')
            ->select('student_id', DB::raw('SUM(obtained_marks) as total_marks'))
            ->groupBy('student_id')
            ->get();
```

My out put of this query is following , which is as per my need but i am facing difficulty to display the data in my blade [image]

in my view when i use foreach loop to display the sum results , it got printed in a one array. For Loop is given below

```
     @foreach($users as $names)
     <td>{{$names->studnent_id}}</td>
     <td>{{$names->total_marks}}</td>
     @endforeach
```

When i do this following view comes [image: Current Output]

**Desired out put**

student_id -------------------obtained_marks

1-------------------------------30

2 ------------------------------70

3-------------------------------60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing rows there mate.

```
@foreach($users as $names)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$names->student_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$names->total_marks}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: looks fine , i am trying

Comment: @user7597883 Solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with a table always remember `td` comes under `tr` tag. So your modified code be like:

```
@foreach($users as $names)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$names->student_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$names->total_marks}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

On each iteration a new `tr` is created under which there are `td's`

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue.
You did not spell your key properly. 
In your foreach loop. Change studnet_id to student_id
In the future,  turn on error reporting and notices while working in your development environment.  This will help.